# How Encrypt with AES CBC Zero Padding in Javascript and decrypt with Java

Tags: javascript, java

I need encrypt in Javascript and Decrypt in Java but when i encrypt in Java the text is diferent, i used a diferent script but same algorithm, AES-128 CBC Zero Padding.

This is for Javascript and Java 7 in Intellij IDEA

Javascript:

```
   var message = "3258";
   var key = "CLAVE00000000000";
   var iv  = "VECTOR0000000000";

   var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, key,  {iv: iv, padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC});
   alert(ciphertext.toString());

   var decrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, key, {iv: iv, padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC});
   alert(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decrypt).toString());
```

Java:

```
KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
keyGenerator.init(AES_128);

String key = "CLAVE00000000000";
String IV = "VECTOR0000000000";
System.out.println("1. Message to Encrypt: " + new String(message, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

byte[] cipherText = encrypt(key, IV, message);
System.out.println("2. Encrypted Text: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText));

byte[] decryptedString = decrypt(key, IV, cipherText);
System.out.println("3. Decrypted Message : " + new String(decryptedString));
```

I expect the cipher text identical in Javascript or in Java, but the values are diferent

Comment: what's the value you get in Java?

Comment: In Javascript is: U2FsdGVkX1/3H3/VO8b5gjCk3XZfXkSK9JpgmPGYjtk=

Comment: In Java is: sEAtASy0J3+Ya3g+Afcj3Q==

Comment: The message is: 3258

Comment: Same algorithm = same result for the same input. Please show your more of Java code, it is missing the must relevant methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JavaScript-code key and iv have to be passed as `WordArrays`. For this purpose `CryptoJS` provides conversion functions:

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse("CLAVE00000000000");
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse("VECTOR0000000000");
```

If the key is passed as a string (as it is the case in the posted code), it is treated as a passphrase and used to derive a key and IV (see [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/), section *The Cipher Input*).

Furthermore, in the JavaScript-code Zero-Byte-Padding must be replaced by Pkcs7-Padding (`padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7` instead of `padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding`) in the `encrypt`- and `decrypt`-call.

Then the encryption of the JavaScript-code corresponds to that of the Java-code (`sEAtASy0J3+Ya3g+Afcj3Q==` for the used message, key and IV).

The replacing of the padding is a guess because the `encrypt`- and `decrypt`-methods of the Java-code have not been posted, so that a direct check is not possible. However, with regard to the same encryption when switching to Pkcs7, this should be true.

Comment: Thanks a lot Topaco